# How to select the first child of each element in jQuery using one selector query

Tags: jquery, css

I need a selector query to get the first `<span>` element of each `<li>` element

```
<li><span>a1</span><span>b1</span></li>
<li><span>a2</span><span>b2</span></li>
<li><span>a3</span><span>b3</span></li>
```

Answer (score 1):

Consider using [`:first-child`](https://api.jquery.com/first-child-selector/) selector: `$('li span:first-child')`.

```js
$('li span:first-child').css('color', '#f00');
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<li><span>a1</span><span>b1</span></li>
<li><span>a2</span><span>b2</span></li>
<li><span>a3</span><span>b3</span></li>
```